# I got a 'Unsupported 16-Bit application' error when I try to create TomEE Plus 9 as a service

Tags: windows, installation, service, java-11, apache-tomee

I aprecciate a lot if you give me some help to create a TomEE service.

I'm using the TomEE Plus 9 at Eclipse and out of it using startup.bat and it is working fine but when I try to create the TomEE service, I receive the incompatibility error below:

[Incompatibility error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdTcH.png)

My OS is Windows 10 64Bits.
JDK 11.0.2
TomEE Plus 9

Below the DOS lines after I executed the 'service.bat install' to create the TomEE service:

[TomEE service install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvZcZ.png)

I'm just want create the TomEE Plus 9 as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

Apparently the TomEE Plus 9 has a problem to create a TomEE service in windows 64 Bits.

I have updated to TomEE 9.1 and the service was created correctly.